# Populating UITableView on a secondary view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have code that has an initial table and when you click an index, it loads another view. I have code that is populating an array correctly, but the code I have just wont populate the table using the array. I have almost the exact same code that I used to populate my main table, but it won't populate. Heres the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

NSLog(@"Questions array = %@", self.answersArray);

cell.textLabel.text = [_answersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

For some reason it wont print out the array. I have the array as a property and being initialized in the viewDidLoad method:

```
    NSInteger row = _indexOfQuestion.row;
_tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://**.***.**.**/getAnswer.php?num=%d", row];
self.answersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.answersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: _selectedQuestion];
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    _hostStr = [_tempStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"&ans=answer%d", i];
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: _hostStr]];
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [self.answersArray addObject: serverOutput];
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the NSLog you have above?  Do you even see it?  If not, your array is likely nil or empty.  Try a NSLog right after you set serverOutput.

Comment: Yeah, I said that in the question, its populated correctly, because i did a NSLog right after it all got populated and it printed out correctly.

Comment: You need to be more specific.  When you say "I have code that is populating an array correctly, but it just won't populate the table correctly" that's not very helpful background information.  Also, it's not clear from the above if you mean the viewDidLoad method in the parent or sub-table.  All that said...  Try calling reloadData on your table view after you fill in your array and make sure your data delegate is set properly.

Comment: what do you mean make sure your data delegate is set properly?

Comment: your UITableView has a delegate and a data source.  If the data source (what I called the data delegate) is not set properly (is nil) then the table looks empty.  This might help there:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes youre right...i forgot to declare that...duh..thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the things that might have gone wrong -

1. Is the `NSArray` populated with the data? (you said the data is present).
2. If data is present, then see if you have linked `UITabelView` in Interface Builder with the variable in your code.
3. Did you link your `UITableView` delegate and dataSource to the correct file?
4. Did you inherit the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in the `.h` file ?